# java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl cannot be cast to class org.jbpm.compiler.xml

Tags: drools, jbpm

I plan to upgrade drools8, I have a ruleflow in my project, so I tried to introduce jbpm-flow-builder, jbpm-flow and other components, but found that jbpm-flow-builder does not have a corresponding drools8 version, so I tried to use org.kie.kogito jbpm-flow-builder 1.34.0.Final, but found that if the error is reported, how to solve it.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl cannot be cast to class org.jbpm.compiler.xml.compiler.SemanticKnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl (org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl and org.jbpm.compiler.xml.compiler.SemanticKnowledgeBuilderConfigurationImpl are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.jbpm.compiler.ProcessBuilderImpl.configurePackageBuilder(ProcessBuilderImpl.java:101)
    at org.jbpm.compiler.ProcessBuilderImpl.<init>(ProcessBuilderImpl.java:97)
    at org.jbpm.process.builder.ProcessBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newProcessBuilder(ProcessBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:26)
    at org.jbpm.process.builder.ProcessBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newProcessBuilder(ProcessBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:23)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.ProcessBuilderFactory.newProcessBuilder(ProcessBuilderFactory.java:30)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.<init>(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:238)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.<init>(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:147)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl.java:52)
    at org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:52)
    at com.rule.erule.core.engine.init.ERuleSessionAware.generateKbase(ERuleSessionAware.java:263)
    at com.rule.erule.core.engine.init.ERuleSessionAware.getRuleSetKbase(ERuleSessionAware.java:236)
    at com.rule.erule.core.engine.init.ERuleSessionAware.refreshRuleSet(ERuleSessionAware.java:496)
    at com.rule.erule.core.engine.task.RulesetCheckTask.run(RulesetCheckTask.java:22)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Since Drools v6 ruleflow is merged to agenda-group. See [reference](https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_ruleflowgroups_and_agendagroups_are_merged).

You'll need to refactor your code/RHS to make use of agenda-group if you want to use purely Drools 8, or migrate to Rule Unit.

Alternatively, you can consider migrate to Kogito to develop some BPMN or ServerlessWorkflow to coordinate Kogito-based microservices with your DRLs.

Comment: How to refactor your code/RHS to make use of agenda-group?Could u share me the code examples in Drools 8? Thank u~

Comment: here are migration considerations for rule units: https://docs.drools.org/8.35.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/migration-guide/index.html#traditional-to-ruleunit_migration-guide